# How to manually change the Authentication Provider in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

The authentication provider is set in

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
```

Is it possible to change the Authentication Provider during runtime in SpringBoot?

Answer (score 0):

Instance of configured `AuthenticationManager` eventually will be passed to one of the implementations of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. This base filter class has setter for `AuthenticationManager` so yes, essentially you can replace `AuthenticationManager` in runtime provided that you have access to the configured authentication filter.

But I doubt that it would be a good idea because you can have several authentication filters where `AuthenticationManager` should be replaced too. Also Spring does not expect this behavior so finally it can lead to inconsistency in the configuration.

Depending on your needs I would suggest to provide custom implementation of `AuthenticationManager` that changes its logic accordingly to some conditions.